# What do the words "boasts" & "knows mean in Jeremiah 9:24

Tags: word-study, prophecy, authorial-intent, jeremiah

> [Jeremiah 9:24](https://biblehub.com/jeremiah/9-24.htm) but let him who **boasts** **boast** in this, that he
>   understands and **knows** me, that I am the LORD who practices steadfast
>   love, justice, and righteousness in the earth. For in these things I
>   delight, declares the LORD.”

What do the words **boasts** & **knows** mean ? And also what message is this scripture trying to convey to us?

Comment: The Ivri / Hebrew meaning of "yit-Hallel" (יִתְהַלֵּ֣ל) = "let-Boasts" & "'ve-Yadoa" (וְיָדֹ֣עַ) = "and-Knows".

Answer (score 1):

Jeremiah 9:23-24

> 23 This is what the Lord says: “Let not the wise boast of their wisdom
> or the strong boast of their strength
> or the rich boast of their riches,
>
> 24 but let the one who boasts boast about this:
> that they have the understanding to know me,
> that I am the Lord, who exercises kindness,
> justice and righteousness on earth,
> for in these I delight,”
> declares the Lord.

In verse 23, the one who boasts boast the strength of himself, whereas in verse 24, the one who boasts boast his knowledge of the Lord.

The use of the word "boast" in both verse 23 & 24 is rhetorical. It turns a negative meaning of "boast" in verse 23, into a positive use of it.

Verses 23 & 24 must be read together. And the words "boast" and "know" mean exactly what they are. Meaning if one wanted to boast, "boast" himself that he "knows" the Lord; knowing His kindness, justice and righteousness.

Answer (score 0):

According to my Mantis Bible, the English word "boasts" is the Hebrew word "halal"; a prim. root; to be boastful, to praise: - It is most often translated praised or praise.  It is also found in Gen. 12:15; Judges 16:24; I Sam. 21:13; 2 Sam. 14:25; 22:4; I Ki. 20:11; I Chr. 16:4, 10; 16:25, 36; 23:5, 30; 25:3; 29:13; 2 Chr. 5:13; 7:6; 8:14; 20:19, 21; 23:12, 13; 29:30; 30:21; 31:2; Ezra 3:10-11; New. 5:13; 12:24; Job 12:17; Ps. 5:5; 10:3; 18:3; 22:22-23, 26; 34:2; 35:18; 44:8; 48:1; 49:6; 52:1; 56:4, 10; 63:5, 11; 64:10; 69:30, 34; 73:3; 74:21; 75:4; 78:63; 84:4; 96:4; 97:7; 102:8, 18; 104:35; 105:3, 45; 106:1, 5, 48; 107:32; 109:30; 111:1; 112:1; 113:1, 3, 9; 115:17, 18; 116:19, 117:1, 2; 119:164, 175; 135:1, 3, 21; 145:2, 3; 146:1, 2, 10; 147:1, 12, 20; 148:1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 13, 14; 149:1, 3, 9; 150:1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6; Prog. 12:8; 20:14; 25:14; 27:1, 2; 28:4; 31:28, 30, 31; Ecc. 2:2; 7:7; Song 6:9; Isa 38:18; 41:16; 44:25; 45:25; 62:9; 64:11; Jer. 4:2; 9:23, 24; 20:13; 25:16; 31:7, 46:9, 49:4; 50:38; 51:7; Exek. 26:17; Joel 2:26; and Nah. 2:4.

The English word translated "knows" is the Hebrew word "yada" a prim. root; to know.  It refers to ability, acknowledge, acquaintances, acquainted, aware, becomes known, bring forth, cared, chosen, clearly understand, cohabit, comprehend, concern, concerned, consider...It is most often translated know (542 times) Known (65 times)...other less common translations are raped, satisfied, understand, provided.  There are too many places this word is found in the Bible to identify each.

Jer. 9:23-24 is quoted in I Cor. 1:31 regarding boasting in the LORD.  We also see this concept in Ps. 20:7; 44:8; 2 Cor. 10:17; Gal. 6:14.  Instead of boasting in what we have or have done, our boast need be in Christ who gave us the strength and power to achieve what we have achieved.

Regarding "know", there is a huge difference between knowing about someone and truly "knowing" them.  God wants us to truly "know" Him.

I hope this is helpful.

Gloria

Comment: So a simple translation would be "but let him who praises praise in this, that he understands and knows me" so what would "praise in this" imply? "to feel good and talk about this" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The original Ivri / Hebrew of Jeremiah 9:23 [MT] states : "23 But **let (him that) boasts** exult in this, that he understands **and knows** Me, for I am YHVH Who practices kindness, justice and righteousness on the earth; for in these things I delight, says YHVH." (כִּ֣י אִם־בְּזֹ֞את יִתְהַלֵּ֣ל הַמִּתְהַלֵּ֗ל הַשְׂכֵּל֘ וְיָדֹ֣עַ אוֹתִי֒ כִּי אֲנִ֣י יְהֹוָ֔ה עֹ֥שֶׂה חֶ֛סֶד מִשְׁפָּ֥ט וּצְדָקָ֖ה בָּאָ֑רֶץ כִּֽי־בְאֵ֥לֶּה חָפַ֖צְתִּי נְאֻם־יְהֹוָֽה)

**What do the words "let-boasts" and "and-knows" mean in Jeremiah 9:23 [MT]?**

- "yit-Hallel" (יִתְהַלֵּ֣ל) = "let-Boasts";
- "'ve-Yadoa" (וְיָדֹ֣עַ) = "and-Knows".

**The English bible translates YHVH as "the Lord" & changes the verse order of Jeremiah 9:23, placing it at verse 24  in the KJV.**

**Jeremiah 9:24 [KJV]**

> "
> But let him **that glorieth** glory in this, that he understandeth **and knoweth** Me, that I am the Lord which exercise lovingkindness, judgment, and righteousness, in the earth: for in these things I delight, saith the Lord."

**What does Jeremiah 9:23 [MT] and Jeremiah 3:24 [KJV] mean?** - Testify about God by celebrating in His praise (if you understand, know YHVH is the source of Kindness, Justice & Righteousness on Earth)!